# Edit time in mysql output

Tags: php, html, mysql

Have a question, I found this:

http://www.phpdevtips.com/2013/06/email-open-tracking-with-php-and-mysql/

So was able to get it working  and even figured out how to show the data in a page, this one:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="900">
<title>Who read his e-Mail, and when?</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.txt {
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 11px;
text-align: left;
}

h2 {
padding: 5px;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 24px;
text-align: left;
font-weight: bold;
}

#myTable {
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
font-size: 18px;
}

#myTable th, #myTable td {
text-align: left;
padding: 12px;
}

#myTable tr {
border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myTable tr.header, #myTable tr:hover {
background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>


<h2>Who read his e-Mail, and when?</h2>

<?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "***", "***") or die (mysql_error ());

mysql_select_db("***") or die(mysql_error());

$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM email_log";

$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {

echo "<table border='1' width='100%' style='border-collapse: collapse' cellpadding='5' class='txt' id='myTable'>";
echo "<tr class='header'>";
echo "<td width='5%' class='txt'>";
echo $row['id'] . "</td><td width='30%' class='txt'>";
echo $row['user'] . "</td><td width='40%' class='txt'>";
echo $row['subject'] . "</td><td width='25%' class='txt'>";
echo $row['opened'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
}

mysql_close();

?>

</body>
</html>
```

---

So far, so good, now my question is, the date and time that get´s pulled out of the database in the row **opened** is showing like this on the result page: `2017-03-09 07:53:58`

I would like it to show as `07:53:58 09-03-2017`

and it should be 6 hours later, as this seems to me that what it is showing now is server time, not our timezone.

So reaching out for your help, anyone can give me a push into the right direction? Any Help appreciated.

Joris

Comment: Read about the PHP [date & time](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) classes.

Comment: **Stop** using deprecated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Comment: Is `opened` field  set with `DATE` datatype ?

Comment: `echo date('H:i:s d-m-Y', strtotime($row['opened'])+21600);` Adds 6hrs

Answer (score 0):

For changing the date format you can use

**date('h:i:s d-m-Y', strtotime($row['opened']));**

The best way to manage the time zone, you can set a timezone, at the place where you are inserting the date time to database. Initialise the timezone what you want before mapping to database.

**date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Bangkok");**

instead of "Asia/Bangkok" you can give your timezone

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, great solutions, this one did it best:

echo date('H:i:s d-m-Y', strtotime($row['opened'])+21600);

Tnx, Greetz from Spain :)

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(opened,'%H:%i:%s %d-%m-%Y')opened,id,user,subject FROM email_log
```

You can try `DATE_FORMAT()`of `MySQL`.
Try above code hope this will helps.